# Sorting data by a set of comparisons

Tags: c++, sorting

Given input data in the form of many comparisons, such as 'a > b', 'd < b', 'c > a', ...

How can I construct a sorted (greatest to least) ordering? (I don't have to worry about being given impossible inputs; there will always be exactly one correct ordering.)

I was thinking about writing a function as a parameter to std::sort that would look up each element in the list of comparisons, but I don't think that would handle the idea of transitivity.

Comment: Do you know in advance all of the potential element values?

Comment: @EdHeal Sorry if I made it seem like I'm asking for code. Just looking for a direction to go in, or an algorithm to look into.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I don't--I would have to get that from the input comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need to do comparison-based sorting.

Construct a digraph with a directed edge for each inequality, and run [Topological Sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). This will run in linear time.

The boost graph library has this [implemented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/topological_sort.html).